# Vmware workstation slows down the Host checking the internet presence

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I noticed, installing on my laptop with Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V enabled, VMware workstation (both 15.5 and 16.0), that causes my computer detecting more slowly the internet presence.

To provide an example, when the host system boot, or just resume from standby condition, Windows take several seconds before detecting the internet presence (to allow me to browse in the browser, before that moment the computer behave like missing internet connection). I tried also formatting the notebook and so testing on a clean installation.

Uninstalling Vmware brings everything normal.

To remove every doubt about computer performance, it is a I7 quad core with 32 gb RAM and this happens also without starting vmware (and therefore without starting any virtual machine), so it is not a performance problem.

I think the problem is in someway related to the large amount of virtual interface VMware creates on the computer. Is there some workaround to avoid or fix this annoyance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use VMware (I use this), then:

1. Stick to one version (just use the newest version). Uninstall the unused version.
2. Disable Hyper-V.  Hyper-V and VMware may conflict with each other.

I have VMware V16 on my laptop and Internet is not impeded in any way.

> Uninstalling Vmware brings everything normal

Hyper-V is conflicting with VMware

If Hyper-V is needed, uninstall both instances of VMware, restart and install just VMware V16.  May sure Windows 10 is completely up to date (V2004 19041.508)

Finally, you can remove unneeded network types in the VMware Virtual Network editor. That may improve performance.

Comment: Vmware supports Hyper-v since 15.5, and however the problem shows also without starting vmware. It is something releted to the network adapters.

Comment: May be, but only using one Virtualizer is a better approach.

Comment: I need hyper-v for other services. However the Vmware since 15.5 is able to run VMs exploiting the hyper-v hypervisor.

Comment: I amended my answer:  Make sure just one version of VMware and that Windows 10 is the newest version.

Comment: Only one vmware is installed on a fresh install of Windows 10 Update 2004.

Comment: "I think the problem is in someway related to the large amount of virtual interface VMware creates on the computer."   <-- There are only two devices on my computer (NAT and Host Only which is normal).  If you are using Bridged networking, you can remove both network types in the Network editor. You can remove Host Only as that is not likely needed.